# How do I construct a Python time struct from the day of year?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have the day of the year, or as its called in Python, the tm_yday.
I want to get out the month and day of month.

How can I create a Python time struct from just the day of year?

Comment: try the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the day of the year:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> tm_yday = 59
>>> tm_year = datetime.now().year # current year
>>> datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(tm_year, tm_yday), '%Y %j')
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 28, 0, 0)
```

Comment: `datetime.strptime('{} {:0>3}'.format(tm_year, tm_yday), '%Y %j')`
Python docs says : %j Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number. 001, 002, ..., 366

Comment: I had padding in my original answer, but a quick test showed that it actually is not necessary for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('10', '%j')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 10, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('359', '%j')
datetime.datetime(1900, 12, 25, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('359', '%j').month
12
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('359', '%j').day
25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
foo=datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(tm_yday - 1)
month = foo.month
dayOfMonth = foo.day
```

Year 1990 is an example, try other in the case of leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Datetime date types are the way to go here:

```
import datetime
```

Here's today:

```
>>> datetime.date.today()
datetime.date(2014, 2, 27)
```

And here's Jan 1st of 2014:

```
>>> datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)
datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)
```

To combine into a datetime object:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), 
                          datetime.datetime.min.time())
```